# How much time passes from the battle to the end of The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the very end of *The Rise of Skywalker*

> Rey goes to Tatooine and buries Luke and Leia's lightsabers at Owen and Beru's old moisture farm where Luke grew up.

Obviously some time has passed from the end of the final battle as we see

> Rey has constructed her own new lightsaber.

How much time passed?

Comment: I'm not even sure that time has a meaning in the galaxy far far away...

Comment: @Rebel-Scum I’ll just guess the final battle was a long time ago to Tatooine then.

Comment: There's nothing in the extended novelisation that confirms it. I'd guess a few weeks (time enough to make a lightsaber).

Comment: Unfortunately, no clues from the story "A Eulogy for Snap" in Marvel Star Wars #25 - it takes place after TROS, but the dialog only confirms that it happens after the Battle of Exegol.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Rise of Skywalker graphic novelisation, the scene takes place

> "*some time later*"
>
> [image: A panel from the Rise of Skywalker graphic novelisation with a text box saying "Some time later, on Tatooine..." The panel shows Rey and BB-8 descending the ramp from the ship.]

Evidently sufficient time has passed for Rey to have constructed her own lightsaber based on the Sacred Jedi texts she was deciphering earlier in the film. This implies at least weeks have passed, but the film and supporting materials are coy about the actual gap, presumably in case they needed her to have additional adventures without breaking the canon timeline.